# Merge objects of the same type

Tags: swift

Say I have a struct Coin

```
struct Coin {
    var value: Float?
    var country: String?
    var color: String?
}
```

I have two instances of a Coin; we'll call them coinA and coinB.

```
let coinA = Coin()
coinA.value = nil
coinA.country = "USA"
coinA.color = "silver"

let coinB = Coin()
coinB.value = 50.0
```

Now, I want to merge the values of coinB into coinA. So the result would be coinA whose values would result in:

```
country = "USA"
color = "silver"
value = 50.0
```

I am able to accomplish this with Dictionary objects using the merge() function. However, I am unsure how to accomplish this using custom Swift objects. Is there a way?

*Update*
Here's how I've gotten it to work with dictionaries:

```
var originalDict = ["A": 1, "B": 2]
var newDict = ["B": 69, "C": 3]

originalDict.merge(newDict) { (_, new) in new }
//originalDict = ["A": 1, "B": 69, "C": 3]
```

And I will further clarify, in this function if the newDict does not have keys that the originalDict, the originalDict maintains them.

Comment: Not enough information. What about cases where they have different values for some or all of the properties? (Like a Canadian silver quarter and a US copper penny? in that case none of the properties would be the same. )

Comment: @DuncanC I am wanting it to work exactly as merge works with Dictionary - see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892855-merge

Comment: "I am able to accomplish this with Dictionary objects". Could you show your code for that? That will help to understand what you want as a result.

Comment: @user2908517 Updated with code example of merging dictionaries in Swift

Comment: So, here, you are taking the argument value if dictionaries have the same key. Is it what you want for your Coin as well? Like if coinA.country = "USA" and coinB.country = "Canada", than you want coinA.country = "Canada" after merge? What if coinA.country = "USA" and coinB.country =  nil?

Comment: Note that the code in your question will not compile unless you declare `coinA` and `coinB` as `var` rather than `let`.

Comment: Needs a clearer problem statement. — But judging from what you've said so far, my first thought is: If what you want is really a dictionary-style merge, not write a conversion between Coin and a dictionary? Then you can turn your two coins into dictionaries, merge them, and make a coin from the result?

Comment: @matt That would mean having to catch different data types, since the dictionary would necessarily be `[String: Any]`.  Doable, but seems a bit extreme.

Comment: What does "merge" mean to you in this context? The `merge` method takes a closure which determines how to merge the two values. For example, you could say that if you have a pair of coin objects you would always take the second coin, or that any nil values in the second coin get filled in from the second. You have to define the rules for a merge.

Comment: Given the final code snippet in the question, I assume OP wants the `merge` to always prioritise values in the second `Coin`.  The closure is unimportant to the question.

Comment: I'd like to know why I received a downvote, given I provided a legitimate technical question with code examples..

Comment: @matt the solution I've temporarily gone with is converting the objects to dictionaries, merging them, then converting the merged dictionary back into the object type (via encoder and decoder)

Comment: That's not at all silly! You could certainly stick with that.

Comment: @vikzilla I agree, it's a perfectly valid question. I upvoted you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ultimately, the most efficient way in the fewest lines of code is probably exactly what you'd expect:

```
extension Coin {
    func merge(with: Coin) -> Coin {
        var new = Coin()
        new.value = value ?? with.value
        new.country = country ?? with.country
        new.color = color ?? with.color
        return new
    }
}

let coinC = coinA.merge(with: coinB)
```

Note that in the above scenario, the resulting value will always be `coinA`'s, and will only be `coinB`'s if `coinA`'s value for a given key is `nil`. Whenever you change, add, or delete a property on `Coin`, you'll have to update this method, too. However, if you care more about future-proofing against property changes and don't care as much about writing more code and juggling data around into different types, you could have some fun with `Codable`:

```
struct Coin: Codable {
    var value: Float?
    var country: String?
    var color: String?

    func merge(with: Coin, uniquingKeysWith conflictResolver: (Any, Any) throws -> Any) throws -> Coin {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let selfData = try encoder.encode(self)
        let withData = try encoder.encode(with)

        var selfDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: selfData) as! [String: Any]
        let withDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: withData) as! [String: Any]

        try selfDict.merge(withDict, uniquingKeysWith: conflictResolver)

        let final = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: selfDict)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Coin.self, from: final)
    }
}
```

With that solution, you can call `merge` on your `struct` like you would any dictionary, though note that it returns a new instance of `Coin` instead of mutating the current one:

```
let coinC = try coinA.merge(with: coinB) { (_, b) in b }
```

Comment: First example should be prioritising `with`'s properties to match OP's question.

Comment: OP's question doesn't prioritize either, it seems to me. There are no conflicts in OP's example, so it's not obvious which way it should go. Thus, both ways are as good as any

Comment: Check the last code snippet in the question, that shows an example of how OP wants conflicts handled.

Comment: I don't believe it does. I read it as showing the method signature they'd like to use, but not necessarily the resolution strategy they intend for their structures. OP's intent remains unclear until they comment

Comment: Your first example it is not returning anything

Comment: I just fixed that. That's what you get for copy/pasting from a playground :P

Comment: You shouldn’t force try. It would make your app crash in case of failure. What you should do is to make your method throws so you can manage any error that might occur instead of simply crashing.

Comment: @MichaelHulet The last code snippet clearly shows `69` taking priority over `2` for the key of `B`.

Comment: Your method as it is would never throw. It doesn’t make any sense

Comment: @Samah I understand that. I still think it's addressing what OP wants their method signature to look like, and not necessarily providing guidance on conflict resolution. I still haven't seen OP clear up that question, either

Comment: Note that options default value is [] so it can be just omitted

Comment: `func merged(with coin: Coin) throws -> Coin {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Coin.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoder.encode(self)) as! [String: Any]).merging(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoder.encode(coin)) as! [String: Any], uniquingKeysWith: {$1})))
    }`

Comment: And you can all like this using `do try catch` or force `try!`if you like to `let coinC = try! coinA.merged(with: coinB)`

Comment: Note that I used a single try in the whole method and used merging instead of merge so you don't need to mutate anything inside the merge method. You can also get rid of the forced casting `return try JSONDecoder().decode(Coin.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoder.encode(self)) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]).merging(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoder.encode(coin)) as? [String: Any] ?? [:], uniquingKeysWith: {$1})))`

Answer (score 3):

I thought it would be interesting to show a solution based on Swift key paths. This allows us to loop somewhat agnostically through the properties — that is, we do not have to hard-code their names in a series of successive statements:

```
struct Coin {
    var value: Float?
    var country: String?
    var color: String?
}
let c1 = Coin(value:20, country:nil, color:"red")
let c2 = Coin(value:nil, country:"Uganda", color:nil)
var c3 = Coin(value:nil, country:nil, color:nil)

// ok, here we go
let arr = [\Coin.value, \Coin.country, \Coin.color]
for k in arr {
    if let kk = k as? WritableKeyPath<Coin, Optional<Float>> {
        c3[keyPath:kk] = c1[keyPath:kk] ?? c2[keyPath:kk]
    } else if let kk = k as? WritableKeyPath<Coin, Optional<String>> {
        c3[keyPath:kk] = c1[keyPath:kk] ?? c2[keyPath:kk]
    }
}
print(c3) // Coin(value: Optional(20.0), country: Optional("Uganda"), color: Optional("red"))
```

There are unfortunate features of key paths that require us to cast down from the array element explicitly to any possible real key path type, but it still has a certain elegance.

Comment: Very nice!  I've never seen key paths used that way before, especially the `\\` shortcut.  Learn something every day. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to make the `merge` function specific to `Coin`, you can just use the coalesce operator like so:

```
struct Coin {
    var value: Float?
    var country: String?
    var color: String?

    func merge(_ other: Coin) -> Coin {
        return Coin(value: other.value ?? self.value, country: other.country ?? self.country, color: other.color ?? self.color)
    }
}

let coinC = coinA.merge(coinB)
```

This will return a new `Coin` using the values from `coinB`, and filling in any `nil`s with those from `coinA`.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to change coin A what you need is a mutating method. Note that structures are not like classes. If you would like to change its properties you need to declare your coin as variable. Note that none of your examples would compile if you declare your coins as constants:

```
struct Coin {
    var value: Float?
    var country: String?
    var color: String?
    mutating func merge(_ coin: Coin) {
        value = value ?? coin.value
        country = country ?? coin.country
        color = color ?? coin.color
    }
    init(value: Float? = nil, country: String? = nil, color: String? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.country = country
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
var coinA = Coin(country: "USA", color: "silver")
coinA.merge(Coin(value: 50))
print(coinA.country ?? "nil")   // "USA"
print(coinA.color ?? "nil")     // "silver"
print(coinA.value ?? "nil")     // 50.0
```

Comment: Cool solution (although I'd prefer one where I don't have to manually enter all the properties into the function). I am working on figuring out a generic solution; currently getting it to work by converting the objects into dictionaries, merging those, then converting the result back into the object type.

Comment: All you need is to add a custom initializer with the properties defaulted to nil

Answer (score 0):

This is not a high-level approach like the merge one you shared the link to but as long as you have a struct to implement the merge feature into, it will do the job.

```
    func merge(other: Coin, keepTracksOfCurrentOnConflict: Bool) -> Coin {
    var decidedValue = value

    if decidedValue == nil && other.value != nil {
        decidedValue = other.value
    } else if other.value != nil {
        //in this case, it's conflict.
        if keepTracksOfCurrentOnConflict {
            decidedValue = value
        } else {
            decidedValue = other.value
        }
    }

    var resultCoin = Coin(value: decidedValue, country: nil, color: nil)

    return resultCoin
}
```

}

You can do the same for other properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap it around `protocol`. The idea behind is the same:

- you convert `object`'s to `dict`
- merge two `dict`'s
- convert merged `dict` back to your `object`

```
import Foundation

protocol Merge: Codable {
}

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    func mergeAndReplaceWith(object: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        var origin = self
        origin.merge(object) { (_, new) in
            new
        }
        return origin
    }
}

extension Merge {
     func toJson() -> [String: Any] {
        let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: Any]
        return json
    }
    
    func merge(object: Merge) -> Merge {
        let origin = self.toJson()
        let objJson = object.toJson()
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let merge = origin.mergeAndReplaceWith(object: objJson)
        
        var jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: merge, options: .prettyPrinted)
        var mergedObject = try! decoder.decode(Self.self, from: jsonData)
        return mergedObject
    }
}

struct List: Merge {
    let a: String
}

struct Detail: Merge {
    struct C: Codable {
        let c: String
    }
    
    let a: String
    let c: C?
}


let list = List(a: "a_list")
let detail_without_c = Detail(a: "a_detail_without_c", c: nil)
let detail = Detail(a: "a_detail", c: Detail.C(c: "val_c_0"))

print(detail.merge(object: list))
print(detail_without_c.merge(object: detail))
```

> Detail(a: "a_list", c: Optional(__lldb_expr_5.Detail.C(c: "val_c_0")))
>
> Detail(a: "a_detail", c: Optional(__lldb_expr_5.Detail.C(c: "val_c_0")))

With this solution you can actually merge two representations of your endpoint, in my case it is `List` and `Detail`.